# SSRS Timelime chart

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I'm trying to create a SSRS report that graphically depicts a time lime where a certain status was true. I have included simplified sample data in the grid below. I'm looking to create a chart similar to the image below.

[image]

```
TIME                  STATUS    Person 

2015-07-15 15:04:00        1         A
2015-07-15 15:05:00        0         A
2015-07-15 15:06:00        1         A
2015-07-15 15:07:00        1         A
2015-07-15 15:08:00        0         A
2015-07-15 15:09:00        0         A
2015-07-15 15:10:00        1         A
2015-07-15 15:04:00        1         B
2015-07-15 15:05:00        0         B
2015-07-15 15:06:00        0         B
2015-07-15 15:07:00        1         B
2015-07-15 15:08:00        1         B
2015-07-15 15:09:00        0         B
2015-07-15 15:10:00        0         B
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the same dataset that you provide in your question maybe the best approach could be [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/679058/System-Availability-Charts-in-SSRS)

Moreover I think it would be easier if you give a try changing your query for getting duration of status event. This way you could make a range column chart and build the chart you want.

A custom property makes the trick just set DrawSideBySide to False.

Check these examples:

http://blog.summitcloud.com/2009/11/ssrs-2008-gantt-charts/
http://pnarayanaswamy.blogspot.com/2010/09/range-bar-chart-gantt-chart-using-ssrs.html
http://www.prasannaadavi.com/2012/05/creating-portfolio-timeline-using-ssrs.html

Comment: This isn't exactly what I needed, but I opted for the first option (codeproject link) and put it in a list and grouped by person. Thus replicating the chart for each person.